# php access self::VAR dynamically

Tags: php

I want to access a class property via self, but with a dynamic method name:

instead of

```
self::U_1;
```

I would need something like:

```
$id = 'U_1';
self::$id;
```

Example:

```
class Dimensions extends Enum
    {
        const U_1 = [
            'xxx' => 'A'
        ];

        const U_2 = [
            'xxx' => 'B'
        ];

        static function all() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
            return $oClass->getConstants();
        }

        static function byId(string $id) {
            return self::$id
        }
    }
```

Comment: `self::U_1` attempts to access the class constant `U_1`, `self::$id` attempts to access the class (static) property `$id`. You can combine `U_1` and `U_2` into a single array (having `U_1` and `U_2` as keys) and use `$id` as a key in this array to access the data you need. Or you can use the [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function to access a constant whose name is stored in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self::U_1` attempts to access the class constant `U_1`, `self::$id` attempts to access the class (static) property `$id`.

You can combine `U_1` and `U_2` into a single array (having `U_1` and `U_2` as keys) and use `$id` as a key in this array to access the data you need:

```
class Dimensions extends Enum
{
    const U = [
        'U_1' => [
            'xxx' => 'A'
        ],
        'U_2' => [
            'xxx' => 'B'
        ],
    ];

    static function byId(string $id) {
        return self::U[$id];
    }
}
```

Or you can use the [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function to access a constant whose name is stored in a string:

```
 class Dimensions extends Enum {

    const U_1 = [
        'xxx' => 'A'
    ];

    const U_2 = [
        'xxx' => 'B'
    ];

    static function byId(string $id) {
        return constant("self::$id");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Constant compilation done at the top level,  you are trying to get this constant dynamically, that's why you are getting problem, you can change it to static variable to get is dynamically.

```
<?php
class Dimensions
    {
        public static $U_1 = [
            'xxx' => 'A'
        ];

        public static $U_2 = [
            'xxx' => 'B'
        ];

        static function all() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
            return $oClass->getConstants();
        }

        static function byId(string $id) {
            return self::${$id};
        }
    }
$obj = Dimensions::byId('U_1');
print_r($obj);
$obj = Dimensions::byId('U_2');
print_r($obj);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/984152)

Output

```
Array
(
    [xxx] => A
)
Array
(
    [xxx] => B
)
```

**Another Method**  with `eval("return self::$id;");`

```
    ............
    const U_1 = [
        'xxx' => 'A'
    ];

    const U_2 = [
        'xxx' => 'B'
    ];
    .............
    static function byId(string $id) {
        return eval("return self::$id;");
    }
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/984180)